# Easiest way to start with VST development

Tags: language-agnostic, signal-processing, vst

What are the easiest ways to code a VST plugin?

I'm a sophomore in IT education, and I may need to write a VST as an assigment project for Digital Signal Processing course. This means I will probably have to implement an actual DSP algorithm, so if I'm not wrong, that outrules all graphical modular VST maker software.

I currently have C++ (CodeBlocks + MinGW), Java (Eclipse), Python and Octave at my hand. I can also get Visual Studio, Matlab, or some free language/environment for the task. I have also found [Faust](http://faust.grame.fr/) which is a functional language and I may learn that for this project, because I enjoy learning new languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SynthEdit](http://www.synthedit.com/) is probably the easiest way to create a working VST plugin while getting the chance to write low-level DSP code. SynthEdit can be extended with custom C++ modules. You could write a module containing your custom DSP code to satisfy your course requirements while using SynthEdit for the GUI and the other VST 'glue' type code. Writing DSP code is only one small part of building a VST plugin from scratch.

If you must write a VST plugin and can't use SynthEdit or similar environments I think the next easiest way would be C++ and [JUCE](http://rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php). I don't use either but AFAIK most plugins are written in C++ and JUCE is often praised.

Other VST framework options exist such as [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com/) or [Delphi ASIO and VST Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/) but these are less widely used and you'll likely be more on your own if you run into problems.

Comment: How much of SynthEdit's functionality do you get with the free demo?

Comment: No idea, I don't use SynthEdit. I build VST's with Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are VST modular synths that allow you to custom program the DSP logic, [SynthEdit](http://www.synthedit.com/) comes to mind but there are more. Search for 'vst modular synth'.

If you like to venture into the .NET world, [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com) is excellent for beginners. It has a framework that structures and simplifies the VST plugin standard and comes with samples that demonstrate the common plugin scenarios.